# How to add a repository using apt-cyg

Tags: cygwin, apt-get

In Ubuntu, you can run a line like

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:swi-prolog/stable
```

How to do it using `apt-cyg` in Cygwin windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run **apt-cyg** with the **-m** option to specify a mirror/repository.
So this is what I did to install PHP from the Cygwinports repo.

```
apt-cyg update -m ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports
```

Then I was able to install the packages from that repo.

```
apt-cyg install php
```

Answer (score 4):

Modern interface for `apt-cyg` from https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg is:

```
$ apt-cyg mirror ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports
$ apt-cyg update
$ apt-cyg install php
```

Repo with last WinXP support:

```
$ apt-cyg mirror ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2016/08/30/104223
```

Official main repo:

```
$ apt-cyg mirror http://mirrors.kernel.org/sources.redhat.com/cygwin/
```

[Multi sources support request](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/issues/19) on project github.

**UPDATE** As development under `transcode-open` is stalled since 2016 use updating heir: https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg

Comment: I rolled back the DMCA update; it has long since been resolved (see https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/issues/73#issuecomment-225156152 for details on how it was resolved).